# DataGridView update from nested objects

Tags: c#

In my WinForms project, I have two objects such as;

```
public class Bar 
{
   public string Name {get; set;}
}

public class Foo
{    
    public Bar Bar {get; set;}
    public string BarName => Bar.Name;    
}
```

I have set the DataSource property on the DataGridView to a `BindingList<Foo>`.

**The Problem**

When I update the `Name` property on the `Bar` object the DataGridView column which is bound to `BarName` does not update with the new value (the grid still displays "Test"). For example;

```
List<Foo> fooList = new List<Foo>();
fooList.Add(new Foo() { Bar = new Bar() { Name = "Test"; } });

....

fooList[0].Bar.Name = "New Value";
```

After the Name property is set, the value in the DataGridView column does not update, how can I fix this?

Comment: Call `fooList.ResetItem(itemPosition);` to force the grid updates the display of the passed item. Also, there's `.ResetBindings()` method.

Comment: Turns out there was bug elsewhere in my code, and I was setting the wrong object :)